# Accessing Kubeflow UI by the same domain users

Tags: kubeflow

Kubeflow deployed on GKE. then accessing UI is OK.

But the other users of the same domain cannot access to it. It likes below image.

How could I grant a permission to the other users?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grant specific users **IAP-Secured Web App User** role on [IAM admin](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam).